# Trying to insert date time value into django model but getting invalid format error

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to save my date time values from the datetimepicker into the Django model. I am getting a time format error.

This is the error :
**time data '2020-09-17T10:05' does not match format "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM"**

**My code:**

```
name = request.POST["name"]
date1 = request.POST["start"]
startdate = datetime.strptime(date1, "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM")
start = startdate.isoformat()
date2 = request.POST["end"]
enddate = datetime.strptime(date2, "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM")
end = enddate.isoformat()
e = Events(name=name, start=start, end=end)
e.save();
```

**Update:**

I am not sure if it is e.save() but here is the error i am getting. It does not say anywhere that error is in form.
[image]

**Update (Solution)**:

```
name = request.POST["name"]
date1 = request.POST["start"]
startdate = datetime.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
start = startdate.isoformat()
date2 = request.POST["end"]
   if not date2:
      end = None
   else:
      enddate = datetime.strptime(date2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
      end = enddate.isoformat()
 e = Events(name=name, start=start, end=end)
 e.save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have entirely invented the tokens you've used in your formatting string in the `strptime` function. They bear no relation to what this function is designed to work with. I'm not sure where you got the idea for them from - perhaps you confused it with a function from another programming language?

The correct tokens to match years, months etc. are all list clearly in the official documentation at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes . This link also contains useful examples: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

Reading from those, for your case the correct string should be:

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"
```

So the code for parsing the start date, for example, should be:

```
startdate = datetime.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
```

Demo: https://onlinegdb.com/HyZH8r8Bw

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had tried this method before also. rechecked it but it is still giving error on time format. Error: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'

Comment: This is my date1 data : 2020-09-17T10:05

Comment: I tested it with a really simple script, it works without error: `from datetime import datetime
date1 = '2020-09-17T10:05';
startdate = datetime.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")`

Comment: I am using 12 hr format , can it be the issue? I did try %I instead of %H but still same error

Comment: Where are you using 12 hr format? Your date string is an ISO8601 string. It must be in 24hr format. Your string contains nothing to indicate whether the time is AM or PM, so it will always be interpreted as 24hrs

Comment: Anyway the code works fine as I wrote it. Demo: https://onlinegdb.com/HyZH8r8Bw

Comment: 12 hr format in timepicker , but u r right i checked with other time values it is in 24 hr format . But still it is giving time format error.

Comment: Did you change it for end date as well as start date? I only gave the example for one, but I assumed it would be obvious you have to change it for both.

Comment: My code is printing the startdate like yours but is giving error while saving it to django model

Comment: Right. So it seems I have fixed the error you asked about. Now it sounds like you have a different error. Is it the `e.save()` line which throws this new error?

Comment: all my variable are storing values properly: date1
2020-09-16T13:30
startdate
2020-09-16 13:30:00
start
2020-09-16T13:30:00, yes i think e.save() line is throwing the error but i don't know how to validate if it is the one

Comment: Normally when you run code and it throws an error, the error message / stack trace shows you the exact line. For example, I deliberately broke my demo in this version: https://onlinegdb.com/S1Ua5H8BD . When you try to run it, it clearly shows you that line 11 is the problem, and event prints the problem line directly so you can see. In a web application, it may not print it direct to the screen, but there should be a log file somewhere you can look at instead to see error details.

Comment: It's clearly showing you it's line 223 of your coach_createActivity file, and that it's still an error with strptime. The error `time data '' does not match...` is clearly showing you that you submitted a blank value (hence the `''`), and that it therefore doesn't match the format specified in the strptime call. So if blank values are allowed, you need to make a different path in the code for them which doesn't attempt to parse them as dates. If blanks aren't allowed, then you need to improve your validation routine. None of this indicates that my answer doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry if my statements indicated your answer doesn't work. Yes null fields are allowed in end date.  end = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True), I tried this method to allow null in views.py:  if not date2  date2 = None  but it is giving this error strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None

Comment: So then you need to check if the end date value is blank before trying to use strptime on it. If it's blank, you have to do something else instead. `None` is a null type, it isn't a string value, which is why that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. N.B. Re the "solution" posted in your question...you do realise that `isoformat()` outputs exactly the same string as you parsed to begin with...making the whole call to strptime completely pointless (apart from maybe for validating that the date is a real date, but there might be other ways to do that.). Demo: https://onlinegdb.com/BkBJULISP . Code which outputs exactly what was input into it is usually redundant - as I say, validation may be an exception to that. I don't know what other validation you've got in place, though.